# Unable to access object property except by stringify/parse before the data in Graphql/resolver context

Tags: graphql, resolver

Unable to access my resolver returned object, however, I can see its content, but accessing properties returns an undefined. Only solution I found is using Stringify/Parse on my value.

Using JSON Stringify then PARSE on my Object turns it to be readable, but this is a lame solution :)

```
const MonkeyResolver = {
    Monkey: {
    address: (data, args, context) => {

         console.log({data}); // Returns the actual entire object (monkey>address)

console.log(data.address); // --> Returns undefined

const newData = JSON.stringify(data);
const parsedData = JSON.parse(newData);

console.log(data.address); // --> Returns the address

       }
    }
}
```

My expected object is such as :

Object(monkey)
   address: 
      city
      street

What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Solved : if the reference database model schema manager does not include the properties, graphql prevent using the properties. I had to check out my defined schemas and solved by adding the needed object properties.